# How is a half-odd integer spin field defined in the Wightman axioms?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spinors, cpt-symmetry, wightman-fields

Can anyone give me a proper definition of 'half-odd integer spin fields' in terms of the Wightman axioms? I'm trying to prove the anti-unitarity of the PCT operator in 'PCT, Spin and Statistics, and all that.' by Streater and Wightman, but for that I need to know what they mean by this and I cannot find a proper definition anywhere.

Comment: A field has half-integer iff the matrix $S$ in eq.3-4 (pg. 99) is a spinorial representation of the Lorentz group. Example *c)* on that page concerns a Dirac field.

Comment: and what is a spinorial representation of the Lorentz group?

Comment: In four dimensions, it is such that $S_x^2+S_y^2+S_z^2=j(j+1)$, with $j$ a half-integer. In an arbitrary number of spacetime dimensions, the definition is slightly trickier (essentially, those representations of $\mathrm{Spin}(d)$ that are not representations of $\mathrm{SO}(d)$; this is easy to tell given the Dynkin labels of the $\mathfrak{so}(d)_{\mathbb C}$ representation).

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't really help me much. The thing I'm stuck with is that I have no information on this power 'F' in equation 3-66 on page 131. Is there any condition? For example, if F would be even, it would solve my problem..

Comment: Essentially, a field $\varphi_{(\alpha)(\dot\beta)}$ is spinorial iff $|(\alpha)|+|(\dot\beta)|\neq 0\ \mathrm{mod}\ 2$. From this, you should be able to determine $F$.

Comment: what do you mean with 0 mod 2? isn't that just zero?

Comment: $1\neq 0\ \mathrm{mod}\ 2$...

Comment: I don't see how I can get F from this..